# Docker deployment options but keeping same container

Tags: docker

Is there a way to deploy docker but have it keep using the same container instead of creating a new container on each deployment restart?

So the problem is we need to use the same container because we are storing state in the form of Linux user account info, so if a new container is created, the app will lose all the previous Linux user account data. I know this is not ideal and we are working on removing this requirement.
I tried "docker stack deploy" but on restart, it will destroy the current container and create a brand new container each time.

We are currently using docker-compose which works with this but we want to move to a distributed computing setup with workers on different machines.

Can docker-compose work across multiple different host machines?
Can kubernetes handle this style of deployment or do I have to manually spin up docker containers?

Comment: Define a volume for the data you want to keep: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: But linux user accounts are not ordinary files. How can I persist linux user accounts between docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

In order to persist the data inside a container you must define a volume.

This way you can re-create or scale you application and keep the data.

Volumes can be defined on the docker-compose file this way:

```
volumes:
# Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
- /var/lib/mysql

# Specify an absolute path mapping
- /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql

# Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
- ./cache:/tmp/cache

# User-relative path
- ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro

# Named volume
- datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Yes but in my case, I need to persist Linux user accounts inside of the docker container, which are not just ordinary files. How can I persist Linux user accounts inside a docker container?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "persist Linux user accounts"?

Comment: Let's say I create a linux user inside a docker container named "bob". When the container gets recreated, the linux user account "bob" disappears. He can no longer login to the docker container using services like SSH for example.

Comment: uhmm... you have an interesting case here. You may want to create the user on the filesystem on you DockerFile before create the container.